# #pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:16777216")

Tags: c++

What does it mean ?

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:16777216")
```

I have been studying a code in from different cpp coders after a codechef programing challenge and i found this. But i don't get it .

Comment: It can fix stack size, without it, stack over flow can be occured in very deep recursive program. It is only available in MS visual c++ also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what compiler you use. My guess is that this is for some windows compiler (because of the / for options) and that it asks the linker to set the entry in the program header which the operating system reads to see how much memory to reserve for the stack when loading the program.

Comment: Nitpick: This applies to the initial thread, the stack size of other threads is controlled by a parameter to `CreateThread` and can be changed independently.

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation:

[Pragma Directives and the __Pragma Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx)

[comment (C/C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx)

[Linker Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx)

[/STACK (Stack Allocations)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx)

> /STACK:reserve[,commit]
>
> The /STACK option sets the size of the stack in bytes. Use this option only when you build an .exe file.
>
> The reserve value specifies the total stack allocation in virtual memory. For ARM, x86 and x64 machines, the default stack size is 1 MB.
>
> commit is subject to interpretation by the operating system. In Windows WindowsRT it specifies the amount of physical memory to allocate at a time. Committed virtual memory causes space to be reserved in the paging file. A higher commit value saves time when the application needs more stack space, but increases the memory requirements and possibly the startup time. For ARM, x86 and x64 machines, the default commit value is 4 KB.